# Kivy TabbedPanel. How to call switch_to from another class?

Tags: python, kivy

In below code I need the button on the `edit_button_tab` to switch to `edit_input_tab`. I really need to switch it that way as I need to switch between predefined classes `EditButton` and `EditInput`. This is a part of a bigger program  with few `Buttons` in different location of a layout and I cant define them within `<MainTabbedPanel>` class. I've tried many ways to call `switch_to` (example in the quotes) but they didn't work.

**CODE**

```
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelStrip
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.factory import Factory

theRoot = """
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<EditButton>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Switch to Edit Screen'
        on_press: root.change_tab('edit_screen')

<EditInput>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:

<UnCloseableHeader>
    color: 0,0,0,1

    disabled_color: self.color
    # variable tab_width
    text: 'tabx'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: self.texture_size[0] + 40
    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        size_hint: None, None
        size_y: 20
        padding: 3
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: root.text

<MainTabbedPanel@BoxLayout>
    size_hint: (1, 1)

    default_tab: edit_button_tab
    tab_width: 130
    FloatLayout:
        EditButton:
            id: edit_button
        EditInput:
            id: edit_input

    UnCloseableHeader:
        id: edit_button_tab
        text: 'Edit'
        content: edit_button.__self__

    UnCloseableHeader:
        id: edit_input_tab
        text: 'Edit Tab'
        content: edit_input.__self__

MainTabbedPanel:    

"""

class EditInput(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class EditButton(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_tab(self, tab):
        print('TAB', tab)
        #call switch method from MainTabbedPanel
        '''the way I've tried
        mtp = MainTabbedPanel
        mtp.switch_to('edit_input_tab')'''


class MainTabbedPanel(TabbedPanel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainTabbedPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def switch(self, tab):
        print("SWITCH TO", tab, self.ids.keys())
        self.switch_to(self.ids[tab])

class UnCloseableHeader(TabbedPanelHeader):
    pass

Factory.register('UnCloseableHeader', cls=UnCloseableHeader)


sm = Builder.load_string(theRoot)

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

**EDIT**

I've tried with below snippet. It prints `IDS` of `MainTabbedPanel` but does not change the tabs.

```
class EditButton(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_tab(self, tab):
        print('TAB', tab)
        MainTabbedPanel.tab = tab
        MainTabbedPanel()
        #call switch method from MainTabbedPanel
        '''the way I've tried
        mtp = MainTabbedPanel
        mtp.switch_to('edit_input_tab')'''

class MainTabbedPanel(TabbedPanel):
    tab = ''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainTabbedPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tabs_showing = True
        if self.tab != '':
            Clock.schedule_once(self.switch)

    def switch(self, dt):
        print("SWITCH TO", self.tab, self.ids.keys())
        self.switch_to(self.ids[self.tab])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `App.get_running_app()` to get an instance of your app
2. Use `root` to get an instance of your root

## Snippets

```
def change_tab(self, tab):
    print('TAB', tab)
    mtp = App.get_running_app().root
    mtp.switch_to(mtp.ids.edit_input_tab)
```

## Notes

- In your kv, you defined a Dynamic class,
  `<MainTabbedPanel@BoxLayout>`. It should be a class rule,
  `<MainTabbedPanel>` because in your Python code, you have defined
  `class MainTabbedPanel(TabbedPanel):` i.e. inheritance mismatch and
  class type mismatch.

Comment: It works when after I' ve changed `mtp.ids.edit_input` to `mtp.ids.edit_input_tab`. Awesome!